# Why do we say "pound feet of torque" when stating torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, conventions, torque, units

This is kind of a grammar question, but when stating a measurement, like distance, force, time, or volume, we generally say 5 gallons, 50 lbs, or 10 miles etc. It is understood we are talking about the volume or the distance.

However, when we talk about torque, some times we say "Torque is 10 ft-lbs." Text books do and in engineering we do. But watching car videos or such, people also say "10 ft-lbs OF TORQUE".....isn't that redundant? We know the 10 ft-lbs corresponds to torque, and it the measure/amount of torque.

I know English isn't perfect. Is it just habit and clarification, as to not confuse it with moments, energy, work, as they share common units?

Comment: Yeah, it's because of the other useful quantities which have those units.

Comment: Outside of the USA a "pound" is not even a unit of force. It's just another crazy US unit like "horsepower" and "tons of air conditioning."

Comment: Do you say somebody is 2 meters tall, or that they are 2 meters? It is a common language usage, that is all.

Comment: Kind of figured that, it was language/cultural usage. Your right, we don't say things like "you 5 feet". Instead we say they "you are 5 ft tall" or "5ft of height"

Comment: Where, @alephzero, is a pound not a unit of force? Not a commonly used unit many places, sure, but it's still a unit and only of force as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Brick - quite confusingly, "pound" can be either a unit of mass (with the poundal as the unit of force), or force. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot%E2%80%93pound%E2%80%93second_system#Variants and be thankful for metric systems which have their own confusions....

Comment: This has nothing to do with physics

Comment: @ fqq, it have everything to do with it, because if you cannot speak or understand correctly the units of discussion, then the physics wont be any good either.

Comment: As opposed to "feet-pound"? I mean we do say "inch-pound", but not "pound-inch". And we do say "kilogram-meter" when it really means kilogram-force meter.

Comment: @JAlex, we once had a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575349/22927) from someone whose instructor insisted the units of torque should be meter-newtons instead of newton-meters.

Comment: @ThePhoton - ughh, a teacher that does not understand the _concepts_ they are teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's convention and a judgement about whether the meaning will be clear if we state a quantity without also stating its meaning.

We also might say the engine has "2 liters displacement" (rather than just "2 liters"), or "200 braking horsepower" (rather than just "200 hp").

On the other hand if we say a milk jug has "2 liters" we can be pretty confident the listener will understand we're talking about the capacity of the jug to hold milk rather than some other characteristic of the milk jug.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's because of the other useful quantities which have those units.

Answer (score 1):

It is because pound-feet correspond to torque, but *not only* torque. Energy has the same physical dimension of $\mathrm{kg \cdot m^2 \cdot s^{-2}}$ or $\mathrm{lbs \cdot ft^2\cdot s^{-2}}$, yet they are not directly comparable.

In case of torque this is the result of a cross product of two vectors $\vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ (length of the lever arm multiplied by the force); while with energy this is a dot product $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{F}$ (force multiplied by the distance over which it acted, while also considering the cosine of the angle between them).

Another bad habit that can be seen here is the implicit assumption of standard gravity $g$.  This used to be common with SI units and "kilogram-force" $\mathrm{kg_F}$ or kiloponds $\mathrm{kp}$, but is now seen very rarely. However, with Imperial and US customary units this usage is still fairly common, "pounds" are often used both as a unit of mass, and as a unit of force, written as $\mathrm{lbf}$ or $\mathrm{lb_f}$.

So a "pound foot" could, in different context, also mean a **pound-foot of energy** – that is, the energy expended in moving one pound (of force) over a distance of one foot, while implicitly assuming standard gravity $g_0$. However, historically this was solved in English by changing the order and calling this unit a **foot-pound** instead. The unit can still be encountered in various texts, for instance when describing muzzle energies of small arms.

Answer (score 1):

> But watching car videos or such, people also say "10 ft-lbs OF
> TORQUE".....isn't that redundant?

It is necessary to specify torque since ft-lbs is also a unit for work which is not the same thing as torque.

Hope this helps.